# error in updating the list of json strings using python3

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to insert another `key:value` list of the `data` while print/storing in another result. Here is what I did till now:

```
>>> data = list()
>>> data.append({'data':'a','name':'alpha'})
>>> data.append({'data':'b','name':'beta'})
>>> data.append({'data':'c','name':'charlie'})
>>> data
[{'data': 'a', 'name': 'alpha'}, {'data': 'b', 'name': 'beta'}, {'data': 'c', 'name': 'charlie'}]
>>> names = []
>>> count = 0
>>> for i in data:
...     names.append(data[count]['name'])
...     count = count + 1
...
>>> names
['alpha', 'beta', 'charlie']
>>> txt = 'alpha'
>>> res = process.extract(txt,names)
>>> res
[('alpha', 100), ('charlie', 33), ('beta', 22)]
>>> for name, score in res:
...     print(data[names.index(name)])
...
{'data': 'a', 'name': 'alpha'}
{'data': 'c', 'name': 'charlie'}
{'data': 'b', 'name': 'beta'}
>>> for name, score in res:
...     print(data[names.index(name)]['score'] = score)
...
  File "<stdin>", line 2
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

Kindly, let me know what I need to do, do that I get the result with added `key:value`. I am trying to get the output  like this:

```
{'data': 'a', 'name': 'alpha', 'score': 100}
{'data': 'c', 'name': 'charlie', 'score': 33}
{'data': 'b', 'name': 'beta', 'score': 22}
```

Comment: you cannot `print` and assign at the same time. Just assign, and print result later.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I tried like this `result = (data[names.index(name)]['score'] = score)` still not working. Please can you share something workable for me. please.

Comment: `data[names.index(name)]['score'] = score` that assign.

Comment: I am getting this error `>>> for name, score in res:
...     (data[names.index(name)]['score'] = score)
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    (data[names.index(name)]['score'] = score)
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax` now what I need to do.

Comment: assignments cannot be in parentheses. Remove them.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre this realy helped a lot. Thank you.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I don't think so that the my question is related with any of the references. But anyways thank you.

Comment: it is closely related: assigning to a variable isn't like C: you cannot assign, then use the "returned value". It's not syntaxically correct. So yes, it's the same issue you have (or else I wouldn't have thought of those duplicates)

Answer (score 2):

In Python, assignment (here `data[names.index(name)]['score'] = score`) is a statement, so you cannot use it where an expression is expected. You have to first do the assignment, then print the result, ie replace this:

```
for name, score in res:
    print(data[names.index(name)]['score'] = score)
```

with:

```
for name, score in res:
    index = names.index(name)
    data[index]['score'] = score
    print data[index]
```

As a side note:

```
names = []
count = 0
for i in data:
    names.append(data[count]['name'])
    count = count + 1
```

is an incredibly complicated way to write:

```
names = [item["name"] for item in data]
```

Comment: you should explain why OP is wrong, not just dump working code.

Comment: Indeed...  Done.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
for name, score in res:
    print(data[names.index(name)]['score'] = score)
```

with

```
for name, score in res:
    for d in data:
        if d['name']==name:
            d['score'] = score
```

Though it might be a better approach to use classes.